# access control on protocol implementation init

Tags: swift, singleton, protocols

Trying to enforce an access control for a protocol that will be implemented by a singleton class.
I would like the class to have a fileprivate init, is there a way to enforce this behaviour?
Since a protocol is not a class i cannot put the init in the protocol extension.

Comment: You can't. You can't use a protocol to force a class to restrict access to something, because all the implementations of the requirements of the protocol need to be as accessible as the protocol itself. If the protocol is `internal`, then all the implementations of its requirements need to be `internal`.

Comment: Besides... based on your comments below it seems that the reason you want to do this is to ensure that the class that implements the protocol is a singleton. But even if you could use a protocol to restrict the access control level of an initialiser, that doesn't prevent the class from having a _different_ initialiser that's more accessible. Just having a `fileprivate` initialiser doesn't ensure that the class is a singleton; it has to be the _only_ initialiser for the class.

Comment: I am aware of that, that's why i was thinking that maybe subclassing would allow me to do this, with the init in the parent class, seems it is not possible though.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple docs:

> The access level of each requirement within a protocol definition is automatically set to the same access level as the protocol. You cannot set a protocol requirement to a different access level than the protocol it supports. This ensures that all of the protocol’s requirements will be visible on any type that adopts the protocol.

Link [Protocol docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html)

EDIT: I have misread the question a bit.

If I understood OP's clarification, the only way I know at the moment to ensure that class is singleton is to mark its init method as private or fileprivate.

For my simple singleton with only static methods I have this:

```
private init() {

}
```

Comment: Not what i asked mate sorry

Comment: @thibautnoah you can just declare init `fileprivate`. If I am mistaken again please clarify what exactly you mean by enforcing.

Comment: Future me might be stupid enough to not look at the documentation i wrote for my framework.
I want to make sure future me won't forget to mark the init as private or already have a private init.
I'm thinking subclassing + protocol but not sure it will allow me to do what i want

Comment: @thibautnoah Well, like I written in my answer, unfortunately, you can't do that in protocol. I think if you mark the designated initializer as private in your singleton class, you won't be able to create other instance of that class so it should suffice.

Comment: Seems like you don't get it, i already done that and there might be a way around it.

Comment: @thibautnoah ok, sorry. To my knowledge there is no way in the language at the moment to do what I think you want to do.